# FBSDKAppInviteContent prompting for login

Tags: facebook, swift, facebook-sdk-4.x

I had successfully logged into Facebook using Parse Facebook, when I try to invite friends, it is prompting for login windows on safari browser first (which should be invite friends windows). It is on IOS9 with FB IOS 4.8 SDK. Here is the code.

```
    let content =  FBSDKAppInviteContent()
    content.appLinkURL = NSURL(string: "http://goo.gl/FW")
    content.appInvitePreviewImageURL = NSURL(string: "http://goo.gl/FW")
    FBSDKAppInviteDialog.showFromViewController(self, withContent: content, delegate: self)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, my bad. Browser in private mode

Comment: how you fixed this ?